# iOS ArialMT font size different than in Fireworks

Tags: ios, fonts

I use the following code to set the font for further usage in various labels.

```
UIFont *boldFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:26];
```

The problem I have is that the resulting font appears to be slightly bigger than it should be, i.e. it is bigger than the normal Arial font in Adobe Fireworks.

At least from what I read Arial and ArialMT are the same fonts, but apparently that is not the case when it comes to font sizes.

Is there any ratio so that given font size for normal Arial font in Fireworks I would be able to calculate the appropriate font size to include in my code.

Comment: Have you checked what the value of your labels' `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` and `minimumFontSize` properties are?

Comment: both are set to their default values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can only be solved by using ArialMT fonts in Fireworks.